# Post-upload processing of SSE-C encrypted objects on S3: how to provide the key to the Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, architecture

When using SSE-C, the AWS documentation states that the encryption key is obliterated from RAM right after the objects are put into their bucket on S3.

I need to extract and process some data from my objects right after they are uploaded, but the original objects are to be archived indefinitely. I'm struggling to find a reliable and safe pattern to provide the encryption key to the Lambda function which would be doing the job.

My idea was to use a SQS queue (which also features its own encryption and therefore could contain an event with the key) to trigger the Lambda, but it doesn't seem there's a way I can put the key into the event.

All the other design patterns that I can think of seem frankly terrible. Any idea on how to design a clean architecture to achieve that?

Comment: The whole point of `SSE-C` is that you store the key yourself, outside of Amazon, instead of storing it in a service like AWS KMS or HSM where other AWS services could access the key (if you gave them the appropriate IAM permission). There's no way for Lambda to access that key, unless you are storing it somewhere like a HashiCorp Vault server, and you make that server available to the Lambda function somehow.

Comment: If we are going to have a tag for SSE-C, can it be aws-sse-c or something?  There's already [sse] [sse2] and so on (x86 SIMD instruction sets) which often get mis-tagged on [server-sent-events] questions since that is also often abbreviated SSE. (I'm only here because my question feed includes `sse*` tag wildcard which matched the new `[sse-c]` tag this originally had.  That's not a showstopper in and of itself, and SSE-C doesn't clash with any x86 assembly stuff, but my experience is that short abbreviation tags tend to get mis-tagged with people not checking the mouseover.)

Comment: Sounds fair  @MarkB if you copy-paste this comment into an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: @PeterCordes I already removed the `[sse-c]` tag and replaced it with a more relevant tag.

Comment: @MarkB: I saw that; that's part of why I said "if".  Future questions might want a tag for this new(?) thing, so I thought it was still worth mentioning somewhere it might be seen by people who follow AWS tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of SSE-C is that you store the key yourself, outside of Amazon, instead of storing it in a service like AWS KMS or HSM where other AWS services could access the key (if you gave them the appropriate IAM permission). There's no way for Lambda to access that key, unless you are storing it somewhere like a HashiCorp Vault server, and you make that server available to the Lambda function somehow.